# SharePoint 2010 Documentor

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-enterprise

Is there already existing a tool , I think "documentor" can be his name for Sharepoint 2010 that can output a form of documentation with a description of all db, web application , sites, sub sites , users, configurations , permissions etc. existing on a SharePoint Server ? Or should I go create one using PowerShell ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Documentation Toolkit for SharePoint](http://www.spdockit.com/). It's a really good tool that documents your farm and its configuration and even changes made to configurations.

Comment: There was also this codeplex tool: [Sharepoint Documentation Generator](http://sharepointdocgen.codeplex.com/). It does not include all the functionality you were looking for, but it may be still worth a try if other options are not available.

Comment: found also http://lekman.codeplex.com/releases/view/55953 and some PowerShell commands at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff645391.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SP 2010 documentation with Item level is here..
(thought to share this if any users search the same in future)

[Squadron 2010](http://www.sharepointcto.com/Squadron/Default.aspx)

[image]